# Can't start ghci using emacs

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

when I type the command "C-c C-l" I get this error and i can't figure out what is wrong please help I want to load my file into an interactive session but it just terminates. I do get a few questions about cabal directories but i just press enter on them.

```
("Starting inferior `cabal repl' process using cabal ..." "haskellsicp" nil "cabal" "repl" "--ghc-option=-ferror-spans")
-> :set prompt "\4"
-> Prelude.putStrLn ""
-> :set -v1
<- Preprocessing library haskellsicp-0.1.0.0...

Event: "finished
"

Process reset.
```

Comment: It looks like it is trying to start `cabal repl`, not `ghci`. Can you run `cabal repl` at the command line?

Comment: No, i just get "Preprocessing library haskellsicp-0.1.0.0..." then back to cmd.